# Make Gradle ignore SDK updates

Tags: android, gradle, yandex

I have an Android app with the following dependecies in `build.gradle`:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation 'com.yandex.android:mobileads:5.10.0'
    implementation 'com.yandex.ads.mediation:mobileads-admob:22.1.0.0'
}
```

those SDK versions are periodically changed in the repository and the release version of app stops building with the following message:

```
...\android-build\build.gradle:21: Error: mobileads version should be updated to 6.1.0 [MobileAdsSdkOutdatedVersion]
    implementation 'com.yandex.android:mobileads:5.10.0'
```

while the debug version of the app successfully builds.

How to make release version temporarily ignore this error? (Until I did not update my app code to support new SDK version).

I build the app in QT Creator, but not in Android Studio.